# Graph node position in graphviz in python

Tags: python, graph, graphviz, rank

I've been looking for a while for the way to specify the node position in a graph in graphviz in python. I found [rank command](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/dotguide.pdf) for a subgraph in dot, which is what I am looking for, but I could not find the way to combine subgraph and rank in graphviz in python. I also tried to force node positions, but did not work either. I created a simple example of what I want to achieve.

This is my code:

```
from graphviz import Digraph

top_nodes = ['a', 'b', 'c']

other_nodes = ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'm', 'n']

g = Digraph('test', format='png')

for n in top_nodes:
    g.node(str(n), color='red')

for n in other_nodes:
    g.node(str(n))

g.edge('a', 'd')
g.edge('d', 'g')
g.edge('g', 'm')
g.edge('m', 'n')
g.edge('b', 'e')
g.edge('b', 'f')
g.edge('e', 'n')
g.edge('c', 'f')

g.view()
```

This is the output:

[image: graph]

I want red nodes ('sources') to be on the top of the graph on the same level, the positions of the rest of the nodes is not so important as long as hierarchical layout is preserved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the *rank = same* statement

[image]

```
digraph G {
a b c d e f g m n
{rank = same; a; b; c;}
a->d
d->g
g->m
m->n
b->e
b->f
e->n
c->f
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid the question was about how to get this result using [the python library](https://github.com/xflr6/graphviz), not raw dot language.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: `{rank = min; a; b; c;}` did it for me. I found this answer from search engine but I'm not using python.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the same problem and find out using a subgraph solves the problem.

```
from graphviz import Digraph

top_nodes = ['a', 'b', 'c']

other_nodes = ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'm', 'n']

g = Digraph('test', format='png')
s = Digraph('subgraph')
s.graph_attr.update(rank='min')

for n in top_nodes:
    s.node(str(n), color='red')

for n in other_nodes:
    g.node(str(n))

g.edge('a', 'd')
g.edge('d', 'g')
g.edge('g', 'm')
g.edge('m', 'n')
g.edge('b', 'e')
g.edge('b', 'f')
g.edge('e', 'n')
g.edge('c', 'f')

g.subgraph(s)

g.view()
```

[image output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFJP0.png)

Answer (score 4):

Starting from your code, it's enough to use the subgraph *context*, just add

```
with g.subgraph() as s:
    s.attr(rank = 'same')
    for n in top_nodes: s.node(n)
```

it seems easier than explicitly declaring a subgraph and adding it to the original graph.

By the way, this solution generates the exact same DOT source as the ine in @RaHo answer.

```
digraph test {
    a [color=red]
    b [color=red]
    c [color=red]
    d
    e
    f
    g
    m
    n
    a -> d
    d -> g
    g -> m
    m -> n
    b -> e
    b -> f
    e -> n
    c -> f
    {
        rank=same
        a
        b
        c
    }
}
```